# Closing a web page automatically

Tags: asp.net

I've a web app wherein i need to run a some code for sending email messages everyday. I've put the code inside a web page. I was hoping to open this webpage using a batch file (and scheduling to run it everyday using windows task scheduler) and then automatically closing it once the task is done. How can i close the website automatically after the task is complete. ? 
This is my first web app so please be merciful .

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You should just create a console app and schedule *that* to run everyday.

Comment: @aquinas Its more convenient for me to use web app because the code to generate reports to be sent along with the message is already in place.

Comment: so, make your console app have a reference to your web application, and have it call the method that generates the report. I'm not saying re-implement any code, just reference it.

Comment: @aquinas can you please point me to how to use the classes i created in the code behind file of the .aspx page in the console application. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: 1) Make your class public. 2) Create a new console app. 3) Add a reference to your web project. 4) new YourWebApplication.YourClass.

Comment: @aquinas do i need to create a class library to add the reference ? Because what i have is a website.

Comment: No, you can reference a website and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with javaScript, calling a function with the following code:

```
function closeWindow(){ window.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you wan to run a scheduled task that sends a requests to the url of your page so you can send the mail. But you want to start and stop die web server each time ?

No need. Rather leave it running, http is stateless so nothing will happen till the server receives a request and it's routed to your application.

No need to worry about anything executing, expect if you have some kind of service or async task running ?

But if not then you simply schedule a task and use a script to make a request to the url. We have a handy .vbs script in the office to achieve that.

```
Call LogEntry()

Sub LogEntry()

        On Error Resume Next

        'Declare variables
        Dim objRequest
        Dim URL

        Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

        'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
        URL = "http://example.com/my_daily_update"

        'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
        objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

        'Send the HTML Request
        objRequest.Send

        'Set the object to nothing
        Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I agree with @aquinas (in comments) maybe try to move the logic to a console application that you can execute.

**Let's hope I understood you correctly.**